# Is it possible to get all TypeElements in a package in an annotation-processing environment?

Tags: java, metaprogramming, javac, annotation-processing

I have a couple of packages in a library that contain annotations and base classes. I'm extending javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor in the context of this question.

Is there a way to get a List/Array/Set of java.lang.TypeElement for all types declared in a package? Or even Elements?

Currently I have a workaround that marks classes into groups by using an annotation on a Type that solely exists to denote groups of related objects in the library. Is there a simpler way to group Types together by package (i.e. location) rather than explicit declaration?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer - I used the ProcessingEnvironment instance variable (in my AbstractProcessor subclass) to get [javax.lang.model.util.Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html) instance to perform really helpful Element/Type/Package access:

```
   List<TypeMirror> typeMirrorsInPackage = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
                .getPackageElement("com.example.sample.annotations")
                .getEnclosedElements()
                .stream()
                .map(Element::asType)
                .filter(mirror -> mirror.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Be careful, according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType()): If this is a generic element, a prototypical type is returned. This is the element's invocation on the type variables corresponding to its own formal type parameters.
Apparently the [Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html) class has more helpful utility methods to handle generics.

Comment: What if the package is unknown?
How to get all packages?

Comment: @hohserg You can retrieve all packages enclosed in a ModuleElement, for example : `List<PackageElement> elementPackages(Element element, Elements elements) { return elements.getModuleOf(element).getEnclosedElements(); }`.