# Java annotation processor check annotations of discovered type by class name

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Let's say I have an annotation `@Foo` that indicates some other classes like this:

```java
@Foo({Other.class, Another.class})
public class MyClass { …
  …
}
```

I'm writing an annotation processor for `Foo`, and after going through all the `TypeMirror` magic (see [*Getting Class values from Annotations in an AnnotationProcessor*](https://area-51.blog/2009/02/13/getting-class-values-from-annotations-in-an-annotationprocessor/)) I finally wind up with an `AnnotationValue` that contains a `List<? extends AnnotationValue>` indicating the other classes. I can get those class names like this (code for illustration; not optimized):

```java
List<String> otherClassNames= ((List<? extends AnnotationValue>)value.getValue())
    .stream()
    .map(AnnotationValue::getValue)
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(toUnmodifiableList()))
```

Great, so now I have two strings, `com.example.Other` and `com.example.Another`.

I would like to see if the `Other` and `Another` classes are annotated with `@Bar`. What is the next step?

(Note that the classes `com.example.Other` and `com.example.Another` will likely be in other libraries, such as Maven dependencies on the classpath; the source files for `com.example.Other` and `com.example.Another` will not necessarily be present, and those classes will probably not themselves be included in the rounds for this annotation processor. However I can guarantee that the other annotation, `@Bar`, will be present in the classfiles.)

I'm guessing that if I could somehow convert each string into a `TypeElement`, I could then go through the whole type mirror thing again (or if I just want to check for `@Foo` I could use `typeElement.getAnnotation(Bar.class)`). But how do I get a `TypeElement` for a discovered string such as `com.example.Other`?

I've spent all day wrestling with with annotations, classes, and type mirrors, so I'm going to take a break. Tomorrow the answer may be obvious to me. In the meantime, maybe someone knows an easy solution already. Otherwise, I'll figure it out, add it as an answer, and help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a hint in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42746295), the method I need to get a `TypeElement` for a class name stored in the `otherClassName` variable is:

```java
TypeElement otherClassTypeElement = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
    .getTypeElement(otherClassName);
```

There is another option:

```java
Set<? extends TypeElement> otherClassTypeElements = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
    .getAllTypeElements(otherClassName);
```

As with all of these annotation processing related method, read the API documentation carefully. In this case it is technically possible that multiple such classes could be discovered.

Then for each discovered type element (or choosing the appropriate one), you can use `otherClassTypeElement.getAnnotation(Bar.class)` to check if the other class is annotated by `@Bar`. Note that if `@Bar` in turn has a method that returns `Class<>`, you may want to instead enumerate the annotations using `otherClassTypeElement.getAnnotationMirrors()`; see referenced article above in my question for details on how/why.